# Using blade on supporting unit in A Game Of Thrones

Tags: game-of-thrones

Is it possible to use the **Valyrian Steel Blade** to add +1 strength on my unit which is **supporting** other player during his battle?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is clearly stated on page 20 of the rulebook. (For reference the [rulebook](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/filer_public/30/4f/304f72e3-4fe4-4f91-bfbe-75133161b092/va65_agot2_rulebook_web.pdf) and the [FAQ](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/filer_public/c0/fc/c0fcd94d-ad0e-4ac0-947e-b258356fabfd/va65_agot2_faq_v1_4.pdf).)

On p. 20 it states:

> If either the attacker or the defender holds the Valyrian Steel Blade token, that player now has the option of using its ability to provide +1 to his total Combat Strength. If used, flip the token to its faded side, as a reminder that it cannot be used again this round.

So, no, a supporting player is neither the attacker or defender and so cannot use the Valyrian Steel Blade in that combat.